# What could make Castle Windsor Dependency Injection differ by build config? Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentRegistrationException from name collision

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I support a WPF application with multiple build configurations (local, dev, stage, etc) that uses Castle Windsor for dependency injection, and click-once for deployment.  I had to update the certificates for click-once and when I was testing I started getting `Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentRegistrationException`s but only when testing the stage build configuration.  local and dev build configurations work fine but stage gets the above exception with the following message:

`Component X could not be registered. There is already a component with that name. Did you want to modify the existing component instead? If not, make sure you specify a unique name.`

I tried breakpoint-ing the registration code and it only appears to hit once but the one time is when it crashes..  How else can I troubleshoot this and has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the bin folder and rebuilding made the dependency injection behave.